# Detect a build requested by pull request and one run by any updates to the PR

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I currently have a task that I intend to run only once when a PR is created. Any pipeline runs due to new commits should not trigger the task. I was wondering if there is a way to detect the runs triggered by changes to code in the PR? When I use the predefined variable `$(Build.Reason)` I get back `PullRequest` for both builds(One triggered when PR is created and other when updates are made to PR).

This is what I have in my pipeline and I have enabled build validation for my pipeline.

```
trigger:
- master
pr:
- master
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to differentiate the "PR is created" and "PR is updated" build reasons based only on the predefined variables.

However, you can choose a different route depending on what this task you should only run once is. If it is something that can be wrapped into a service with a public endpoint, you can try leveraging the [Webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops).

So, if this is an option for you, try the following:

- wrap the functionality required to run only on the PR creation into the service with the public endpoint
- create a webhook, choose ["Pull request created"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#git.pullrequest.created) event type and enter the public URL of your service

As a result, your build logic won't branch depending on the build reason, and that specific action will be run by the webhook.

I understand it all sounds like a hack and unnecessary complexity, but it's up to you to decide whether it fits your case. At least, this is possible technically.